# plsql updatee a table value based on the sum of values from another table

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to update a table based on the sum of values from another table.  The process I want to follow is:

1. select ColumnA,ColumnB from Table1 where id = 123
2. get total sum of the values in ColumnA and ColumnB from all returned records
3. update Table2's columnC with the total sum  from above * 5 (or some value) where id =123

So if the return record from 'select ColumnA,ColumnB from Table1 where id = 123

```
ColumnA ColumnB
1           5
3           0
1           7
```

And Table2's columnC would be set to (1+3+1+5+0+7) * 5 where id = 123

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PL/SQL for that.

```
UPDATE TABLE2 
SET  COLUMNC = ( SELECT (SUM(ColumnA + ColumnB))*5
                 FROM TABLE1 
                 WHERE id = 123 )
```